# Show Facebook / Google plus profile image in higher version

Tags: android, facebook, bitmapimage

I am trying to show facebook and google plus profile image on imageview.

For that I am trying some thing like ..

```
URL img_value = null;
                img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+ userProfileID +"/picture?type=square");
                Bitmap mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
                user_picture.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
```

This work great in lower version but not in higher version.

What I need to do for higher versions.

**UPDATE**

Firstly I initaited an AsyncTask for same .. some thing like ..

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    //new RegistrationAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,(String[]) null);
                    new DownloadImageTask(user_picture).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "http://graph.facebook.com/"+ userProfileID +"/picture?type=square");
                } else{
                    new DownloadImageTask(user_picture).execute("http://graph.facebook.com/"+ userProfileID +"/picture?type=square");

                }
```

Here's my AsyncTask class ..

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

       // private ProgressDialog mDialog;
        private ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {

           // mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ChartActivity.this,"Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            Log.d("image", "do in");
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                Log.d("image", "do 1");
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                Log.d("image", "do 2");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", "image download error");
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("image", "do catch");
            }
            Log.d("image", "do out");
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            //set image of your imageview
            Log.d("image", "post");
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
            //close
            //mDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Now again it is working like charm in lower version but not in higher versions of android.

Answer (score 0):

You should get bitmap in background thread because **NetworkOnUiThread** is not allowed in higher versions. So It will throw **NetworkOnUiThread Exception**. I amn posting full working code on **ICS** and give the **INTERNET** permission in manifest.

```
   import java.net.MalformedURLException;
   import java.net.URL;

     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.graphics.Bitmap;
  import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ImageView user_picture;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    user_picture=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.user);
    new ImageTask().execute();
}



private class ImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    Bitmap mIcon1;


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
     try {
        URL img_value = null;
                img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+ userID +"/picture?type=square");
               mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    if(mIcon1!=null)
  {
  user_picture.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
   }
    }
}

   }
```

Comment: Yup it is showing like that .. I also tried same using a separate asyncTask but with no success .. Updating my post ..

Comment: Okay ... let me take a try .. Thanks

Comment: I am able to run complete AsyncTask but image is not been inflated on higher version .. As usual working great in lower version of android.

Comment: Okay .. let me try this one too.. I have Internet permissions defined in my manifest file.. :)

Comment: Your's and mine logic is correct. We both are performing right actions. Problem was due to internet access i.e. access to Facebook from my device ID was blocked... Anyways thanks for your cooperation. I just thought of letting you know so that you can suggest this to some one else too as well .. :)